# Assigning a destination for properties file in a java program

Tags: java, string, inputstream, properties-file

Sorry if this seems like a newbie question and im sure its just a little thing i need to change but it seems like my program cannot locate the destination for a properties file i coded in.

here is my code

```
public String metrics() throws IOException {

        String result = "";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "C:\\Users\\JChoi\\Desktop\\config.properties";

        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
        prop.load(inputStream);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }

        // get the property value and print it out
        String Metrics = prop.getProperty("Metrics");

        result = Metrics;       
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
```

I get a nullpointerexception error everytime i run the code but however, when i put the properties file in the resources folder and edit the string name to...

```
String propFileName = "config.properties";
```

works fine...any suggestions?
EDIT:

```
String result = "";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "C:\\Users\\JChoi\\Desktop\\config.properties";

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
        prop.load(fileInputStream);
```

SOLVED!

```
String propFileName = "C:\\Users\\JChoi\\Desktop\\googlebatchfile\\config.properties";

        BufferedInputStream inputStream;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(propFileName);

        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the full path to a file, then do not try to open it using a classpath search (which is what getResourceAsStream() does).

Instead open the file using an inputsteam that takes a path.
Here is some code:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(propFileName);
```

The following might be a better technique (I'm not sure with property loading):

```
BufferedInputStream inputStream;
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(propFileName);

inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
```

Comment: both seemed to work but out of curiosity what makes the second technique a better solution?

Comment: second technique uses a buffered stream.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to load a file using a classpath-based input stream but specifying a filepath.

This:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
```

Will attempt to search the classpath starting at the root (based on whatever the classloader considers the root).

If you want to load a file from outside the classpath, you probably just want to use something like a FileInputStream instead.

Comment: you can just do new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\JChoi\\Desktop\\config.properties"))